# simple loop not working

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

A simple script

```
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y')"
path="/var/www/vitalii/backups"
sites=("site1.ru site2.ru site3.ru")

for i in ${sites[*]}
do
    echo "$path/$i"
    #tar -cvzf $path/$i_${now}.tgz /var/www/vitalii/$i
done
```

`echo` works as supposed, prints 3 lines but the commented `tar` line doesn't work as supposed, creates only 1 archive, what is wrong? tell me please.

Comment: Take a look at: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329).

Comment: Cyrus's answer seems to be the solution you need. But, next time you have a situation anything like this, tell us the name of the one archive that is created (i.e., _(the date)_ `.tgz`). That would make it much easier to figure it out.

Comment: Oh, also, you might want to consider using `%Y_%m_%d`-like formats for filenames, so lexicographic (alphanumeric) sort order gives you chronological sorting.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the problem @Cyrus pointed out, you're using the sites array wrong. You're actually making two mistakes which (ironically) mostly cancel each other out. First, when you define the array with `sites=("site1.ru site2.ru site3.ru")`, the quotes make it create a single array element, rather than making each site a separate element. Then, when you reference it with `${sites[*]}`, the `[*]` makes it mashes all of the elements together (separated by spaces) (or it would, if there were more than one element), and then the lack of double-quotes around that means it splits the result on spaces (rather than between array elements), and expands any wildcards, etc.

Net result: you aren't getting any of the benefits of using an array, and if any of the sitenames had shell metacharacters in them you'd have ... unexpected ... behavior. In this case it's not likely to cause trouble (the problematic characters are generally forbidden in DNS anyway), but it's better to learn to do this right:

```
now="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y')"
path="/var/www/vitalii/backups"
sites=(site1.ru site2.ru site3.ru)  # If any elements had spaces or other funny characters, you'd need to quote them INDIVIDUALLY

for i in "${sites[@]}"  # Double-quotes and [@] make it treat each element as a "word", even if they contain funny characters
do
    echo "$path/$i"
    tar -cvzf "$path/${i}_${now}.tgz" "/var/www/vitalii/$i"  # ${i}_ keeps it from treating "_" as part of the variable name
done
```

EDIT: as @G-Man pointed out in another comment, using double-quotes around *all* variable references is a good idea. I've fixed this above...

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$path/$i_${now}.tgz
```

by

```
$path/${i}_${now}.tgz
```

Comment: it makes 3 archives now, but the filenames are {site1.ru}_28_02_2015.tgz  {site2.ru}_28_02_2015.tgz  ...

Comment: Use`${i}` not `{$i}`.

Comment: Also, while it might not really matter in this case, as a general rule, all words containing variables should be quoted; e.g., `tar -cvzf "$path/${i}_${now}.tgz" "/var/www/vitalii/$i"`. Also, in this case, `${now}` doesn't need braces and can be `$now`.